# Access to PreviewKeyDown event of richTextBox in userControl

Tags: wpf, events, user-controls, richtextbox

I would like to know how can I get access to event `PreviewKeyDown` of `RichTextBox` in `UserControl`.

For example, I have user Control and in this user control I have only one richTextBox:

Something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Spirit.Controls.RichTextBoxControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <toolkit:RichTextBox Name="RichTextBox" 
                             Grid.Row="0" PreviewKeyDown="?">

       </toolkit:RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I use this control in WPF window.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2.Controls" xmlns:WpfApplication2="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2" Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>

        <Spirit.Controls:RichTextBoxControl Background="Red"
                                            FontSize="13"
                                            Margin="4,4,4,4" 
                                            Grid.Row="0" 
                                            Here I would like to acces to PreviewKeyDown of richTextBox/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I would like have access to PreviewKeyDown of richTextBox, bind some method on this event and have access to KeyEventArgs.

Something like this:

```
   private void RichTextBoxInUserControl_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter )
        {
         //...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the Intellisence wasn't picking up on `RichTextBox...` in Window but you can subscribe to that event like this

```
<Spirit.Controls:RichTextBoxControl
               Name="RichTextBoxInUserControl"
               Background="Red"
               FontSize="13"
               Margin="4,4,4,4"
               Grid.Row="0"
               RichTextBox.PreviewKeyDown="RichTextBoxInUserControl_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```

where `RichTextBox` is the Name of the `toolkit:RichTextBox` specified in your `UserControl`